# locus of point of intersection of family of lines

Tags: geometry

Consider the family of lines $(x-y-6)+\lambda(2x+y+3)=0$ and $(x+2y+4)+\mu(3x-2y-4)=0.$ If the lines of these two families are at right angle to each other. Then find the locus of point of intersection is

what i try

solving lines $x-y-6=0$ and $2x+y+3=0$

$x=-9$ and $y=-15$

and solving lines $x+2y-4=0$ and $3x-2y-4=0$

$x=2$ and $y=1$

How do isolve it Help me please

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first family has those lines that pass through the point $P(1,-5)$ (your calculation has an error). So a typical line in that family is given by
$$(y+5)=m(x-1) \implies y=mx-(m+5).$$
Your second family has a typo (it should be $x+2y\color{red}{+4}=0$). So the point of intersection in this case will be $Q(0,-2)$. A typical line in the second family is given by
$$(y+2)=s(x-0) \implies y=sx-2.$$
Let $L(h,k)$ be the point of intersection. Then
$$m_{LP} \,\,m_{LQ}=-1 \implies \left(\frac{k+5}{h-1}\right)\left(\frac{k+2}{h-0}\right)=-1.$$
This gives:
$$h(1-h)=(k+5)(k+2).$$
Which is same as 
$$h^2+k^2-h-7k+10=0.$$ 
Thus the locus is the circle given by
$$x^2+y^2-x-7y+10=0.$$

Answer (score 2):

Once you have the "hub" point of each family, A and B (as you did ,apart computing errors), the locus of the right triangles having AB as their hypotenuse is just the circle with diameter AB.